# @@sharing view can remove roles that are site-wide, using acquire or other resource?

Tags: plone, roles, plone-3.x

Suppose `ADMINS` is a group that has an `Administrator` role (site-wide).

In a different context of the Plone site (`/Plone/folder`) I would like to use the `@@sharing` view, and remove all roles from the `ADMINS` group and add some custom ones: the problem is that this isn't possible because `Administrator` role for `ADMINS` is site-wide.

Is it possible to remove the site-wide role for just a context in a Plone Site? Or will I have to do this by settings individual permissions on custom workflow states?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@@sharing` manages local roles and user/group roles (AKA global roles) cannot be changed via local roles.  What you can do, however, is not apply the roles using the group (IOW, just leave the group without any roles), then use `/Plone/@@sharing` at the portal root to assign that group local roles there, then in `/Plone/folder/@@sharing` you can uncheck `Inherit permissions from higher levels` and the local roles from `/Plone` will not be inherited there.

Comment: This makes perfectly sense. I forgot I could do @@sharing at `/Plone`.

Comment: Actually, this is too obvious and simple: site-wide permissions and local are different (just checking the code for the `@@sharing` view shows that it calls `get_local_roles`), so that's why "inherit permissions" weren't working: you have to make them all local, but the trick is you make them local at the *highest possible level*. Very clever, elegant and simple. You can't imagine how simple everything my setup has become after yout tip. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it but only use local roles where you need to.  Avoid going hog wild with this.  Global user/group roles are *much* less likely to have problems or cause performance issues.

Comment: Hum, indeed. I haven't though about performance issues. But sometimes a project have too many groups, and each group in a different context,  that this granularity I'm asking for is needed. Doing this `Administrator` as a local role at `/Plone` is going to harm performance for `Anonymous`users?